# What about PARIS then?

Tags: word, cipher, pattern, wordplay

If in an alternate universe `CAMBRIDGE` is renamed as `AIMRFCJKS`, `ISTANBUL` as `TVDHHPLR` and `TOKYO` as `VWCUW`, What would be that of `PARIS`?

Comment: I feel sorry for the citizens of those places in the alternate universe. 'Where do you live again?'

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To decrypt these, we can use

> the [Affine cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher). (To encrypt a message using this cipher, start by transforming each of the letters into numbers, with A=0, B=1, etc., then use the function $$E(x)=(ax+b) \text{ mod }26$$ to encrypt it into a new letter, where $x$ is the number corresponding to the letter you want to encrypt and $a$ and $b$ are keys of the cipher.)
>
>  In this case, we have $a$ equal to the number of letters in the city name, and $b=a-1$. Using `TOKYO` as an example, we have $a=5$ and $b=4$, so:
>
>   `Message:      T  O  K  Y  O`
>   `x:            19 14 10 24 14`
>   `E(x):         21 22 02 20 22`
>   `New message:  V  W  C  U  W`
>
>   Therefore, for `PARIS`, $a=5$ and $b=4$, so we have:
>
>   `Message:      P  A  R  I  S`
>   `x:            15 00 17 08 18`
>   `E(x):         01 04 11 18 16`
>   `New message:  B  E  L  S  Q`
>
>   So PARIS becomes **BELSQ**.

Comment: A well-explained and well-laid-out answer.  Kudos!

Comment: An affine alternate universe... +1 :)

Comment: HIVPIUJ FFJHDD :) Good job.

Comment: Didnt knew about affine cipher... my algorithm was,

code = num2alphabet(alphabet2num(word*length(word))mod 26).

Where A is 1 and B is 2 and so on.
Good one DooplissForce.
Thank you for your interest and time :)